# Wordpress Column shortcodes not displaying the proper size

Tags: css, wordpress, multiple-columns, shortcode

I have a column shortcode plugin but the one_half column shortcodes seem to be going too long in the content area and dipping down to the next line when there are 2 "one_half" columns next to each other. What could be causing this? You can see the issue here https://shuttleexpress.com/seattle/corporate-event/large-group-charters-for-corporates-and-events/ where the benefits and book ahead should be on the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total width of your one_half columns don't add up: 48% width and 4% margin-right.

Try 46% width and 4% margin or a combination that isn't bigger than 50%.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't even think about the margin-right as a percentage adding into the total width. That does fix it, thanks.